# Component to load whenever data is changed

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm having a component with tabs where I will have the input field and when filled should display the input field in other tab.
[image]

This Field I'm displaying in the other tab as

[image]

My code

```
<aura:attribute name="Product_Generation_Grid" 
                    default="{ 'sobjectType': 'HBC_Product_Generation_Grid__c' }"
                    type="HBC_Product_Generation_Grid__c" />
<lightning:tab id="porductDevelopmentDetails" label="Product Development Details Section">
<lightning:input name="Product Name"
                label="Product Name"
                             type="text"  maxlength="80" required="true" value="{!v.Product_Generation_Grid.Name}"/>
</lightning:tab>

<lightning:tab id="summary" label="Summary Section">
<lightning:input name="Product Name"
                label="Product Name" disabled="true"
                             type="text"  maxlength="80" required="true" value="{!v.Product_Generation_Grid.Name}"/>
</lightning:tab>
```

**The Problem** : For the first time it is working fine i.e., when I enter the values and come to the Summary tab the values are displayed. 
For the second time when I go and edit the value, the respected values aren't being displayed in the Summary Tab. How can I load the values?

Answer (score 6):

you can use [force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordData.htm)

```
<force:recordData 
 recordId="{!v.recordId}"
 targetFields="{!v.targetFields}"
 fields="Name, Beds__c, Baths__c, Price__c, Status__c, Thumbnail__c"
 />
```

as from [highlights](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/06/summer-17-highlight-diving-lightning-data-service.html) says

> Once retrieved, the record result is stored in the aura:attribute
>   defined by the targetRecord attribute. The Lightning component then
>   begins to “listen” for that record to be updated by either the
>   standard Record Detail layout or another component on the page.